# Will there be side effects if files are modified when cmake/make is running?

Tags: git, cmake, makefile

I'm currently developing a tool that is used by multiple users. The tool utilize another repo(repo A) as its helper. Users may require different versions of repo A. So sometimes I need to checkout to different commits in repo A and then cmake && make, etc. The process mentioned above is all done automatically. The problem here is that,  user requests may come in at same time, so I need to decide when to apply and release a **build lock** during the cmake && make process. If I do `git checkout xxx` when a cmake/make process is running, will the process be corrupted?
In python, I know that once the program is loaded, you can modify the src files as much as you like. But is it the same when it comes to cmake/make?

Comment: "I know that once the program is loaded, you can modify the src files as much as you like." - You could safely modify only the `.py` scripts. Would you modify some other file, while it is used (e.g. for read) by some `.py` script, the behavior is usually unpredictable.

Comment: Can't you clone the repo and then run the build in the clone? That way each user has an independent source tree

Comment: @knittl I suggested that in my answer but apparently OP can't afford that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do `git checkout xxx` when a cmake/make process is running, will the process be corrupted?

Yes, that is certainly possible.

> I know that once the program is loaded, you can modify the src files as much as you like.

It's not the same thing though since CMake doesn't load *all* the files before starting to work. If you change the files it has to work with while it's compiling, conditions that held true at one point in time during the process may suddenly not be true anymore. The outcome of such a build is unpredictible.

I recommend making a separate `git clone` or [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for each version needed.
If you don't have disk space enough to do so, lock the repo while it's being used so that only one specific version is accessed at a time. Using a worktree should in most situations be ok unless there are extreme differences between the different versions you checkout.

Comment: The original repo is very large, so I can not afford cloning a single one for each request.

Comment: @SwiJason You only need to do an actual `git clone` if the version needed isn't already cloned though. All subsequent requests for the same version can use the same clone.

Comment: But, is it safe to do `git checkout` after Make(not CMake) starting to work? Will it load all src files before it starts to work? Since Make takes most of the time during the process. Thx for taking time answering the question

Comment: @SwiJason _"But, is it safe to do git checkout after Make(not CMake) starting to work? "_ - No, as I mentioned in the answer, changing the files while it's working will lead to unpredictable results. Either make separate clones or lock the repo so that only one specific version is used during builds.

Comment: OK, I get the idea now. I guess i do have to apply a lock when build is running. Thx!

Comment: @TedLyngmo `git worktree` instead of clone takes less space (shared `.git`).

Comment: @phd Yes, that's a very good suggestion. I added that to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you need to lock.  Why don't you just have the build system do the checkout, before it starts the build, rather than having some other process do the checkout asynchronously?  Then you don't need to lock anything since it's impossible for the build to be running simultaneously with the checkout.

Comment: I got the impression that two different cmake builds that need different versions could be started independently, but I could be wrong. @SwiJason Perhaps you could describe the setup in a little more detail?

Comment: @MadScientist In my case, I assume that I have only one copy of repo A and it's used by multiple users. User requests may come in at same time. When one process is already running **build**, there may be another request that wants to checkout to another commit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have already completed the lock version and it works well. I may re-consider the implementation if I need more performance in the future. Thank you for your time